# How to use DCMTK library with javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, dicom, dcmtk

After working with dcmtk in C++, I'd like to use it in javascript but I think it's not as easy as it is with C++.

is there any way to do that ?
thank you in advance.

Comment: A quick google search reveals http://dcmjs.org/. Perhaps worth a try?

Comment: Is it client- or server side javascript that you want to use it with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093378/using-javascript-to-extract-display-dicom-image-data

Answer (score 0):

I agree to John, I would rather advise to seek for a JavaScript DICOM toolkit instead of establishing an interface between DCMTK and JavaScript.

To answer your question, however:

First, make a basic decision if you want to use the toolkit's executables through kind of a scripting layer that is invoked through JS functions or to write C++ - CGI funtions based on the DCMTK libraries. I think it is obvious that the latter approach gives you far more flexibility in designing the DICOM functionality. In the following, I am going to mention executables which can accomplish particular tasks. In case you want to go the CGI way, the source code of the executable is a good starting point to learn how to use the library.

To read the DICOM header information, have a look at dcmdump. It can convert the binary DICOM header format into a text file which can be easily parsed with non-DICOM-aware JS functions.

To create binary DICOM objects, use the complementary tool dump2dcm, which converts a text file in the format that dcmdump creates back to a binary DICOM file.

To render images to a "web image format" (i.e. PNG or JPEG), you can use dcmj2pnm. It takes a DICOM image and renders it with some simple rendering functions (scale, rotate, windowing).

All of these tools provide a lot of options through the command-line interface to control the output.

There are more tools around which may be helpful but without knowing more about the use cases you want to support this is the information I can provide. Please note again, that I explicitly do not want to advise you to use these approaches, as they are very limited in terms of performance optimization and error handling.